# Require input for optional field select widget

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

(My own use case is about taxonomy term reference fields. But a more generic answer is welcome.)

A taxonomy term reference field, single value, not required, with a select widget that shows all terms of the field.

The user should be allowed to leave the field empty, which would mean e.g. "not known" or "none" etc.

But I want the user to make an active choice, and not just skip the field out of laziness.

There could be the default option "- Please choose -", which would be separate from the "- None -" option. Submitting the form with "- Please choose -" would fail element validation.

This would only apply to the (node) creation form. When editing a node where the term is "none", there would be no "- Please choose -" option.

I know I could do this with a new (custom) widget type or with a form alter hook, by adding a new option that will fail validation.

But I wonder if there is an existing solution out there.

Comment: Would JS to record a focus on the widget do the trick (not click, because keyboard interaction is possible)?

Comment: If we use custom js, we can as well use custom php instead..